# How badly can GCH fail?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm interested in "how many" cardinals we can cram between $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$ before ZFC says "nope, too many" as measured by order type.

So my question is (and i don't know if this is well-posed), given a cardinal number $\kappa$, what is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that ZFC proves that $\mathrm{ord}[\kappa, 2^\kappa)<\alpha$? The half open interval is intended to mean the set of all cardinal numbers between $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$, including $\kappa$ but not including $2^\kappa$, and $\mathrm{ord}$ is meant to return the order type of this interval.

Comment: As mentioned below, for regular cardinals ZFC cannot put a limit. Regarding singular cardinals Shelah's PCF theory gives a definite bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be a model of $\sf ZFC+GCH$, and let $F$ be a definable class function on the regular cardinals such that

1. $\kappa<F(\kappa)$,
2. $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)<\operatorname{cf}(F(\kappa))$,
3. $\kappa<\lambda\implies F(\kappa)\leq F(\lambda)$.

Then there exists a model $N$ of $\sf ZFC$ such that $M\subseteq N$, and they have the same ordinals and cardinals, and in $N$ it is true that for every regular $\kappa$, $2^\kappa=F(\kappa)$.

This means that the continuum function is limited only by its most basic properties, and nothing more.

So while $\sf ZFC$ proves that $2^\kappa$ is bounded by some ordinal it is completely impossible to prove which ordinal.

Answer (score 6):

As many as you want. There is no upper bound. The cofinality of $2^\kappa$ must exceed $\kappa$,of course. See Easton's theorem for the details regarding regular cardinals.

Comment: Brian, although I don't doubt that your answer is correct, at the same time it makes no sense to me. In particular, let $A$ denote an infinite set, $B := 2^A$, and $C := 2^B$. Futhermore define that $a,b$ and $c$ are the cardinalities of $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively. Then your answer implies that $|[a,b)|$ is without bound. In particular, its possible that $|[a,b)|>c.$ Suppose this were the case and aim for a contradiction. Since for all $\kappa \in [a,b)$ there exists $K \subseteq B$ such that $|K|=\kappa$, thus $|2^B|\geq|[a,b)|,$ and so $|C| > c$. But $|C|=c$. Contradiction.

Comment: @user18921: Of course $a<b<c$; this is just Cantor. And $|[a,b)|=b<c$. I assumed that this much was already clear. The point is that if $a=\omega_\alpha$, say, $b$ can be any $\omega_\beta$ with $\operatorname{cf}\beta>\alpha$. Thus, $\beta$ can be arbitrarily large, so there can be arbitrarily many cardinals between $a$ and $b$. This doesn’t contradict the fact that there cannot be $c$ cardinals in that interval, because $c$ isn’t a fixed $\omega_\xi$: it’s defined in terms of $b$. Making $b$ very big in comparison with $a$ automatically makes $c$ even bigger.

Comment: Sorry I've been unclear. By $[a,b)$, I was meaning the set of all cardinal numbers $\kappa$ such that $a \leq \kappa < b$. so e.g. GCH says that $|[a,b)|=1$.

Comment: @user18921: Doesn’t materially affect what I said in the last comment; it just means that $|[a,b)|$ isn’t $b$, but it can still be as big as you like: just take $\beta=\alpha+\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is any cardinal of cofinality greater than $a$.

Comment: Hmmm. Well let me chew on that for a bit.

Comment: @user18921: It may help to realize that ‘arbitrarily many’ is measured against the scale of $\omega_\xi$’s (or if you prefer, $\aleph_\xi$’s). Your attempted counterexample involves the scale of $\beth_\xi$’s, but as Easton’s theorem shows, very little of how the $\beth$s fit into the $\aleph$s is determined by the axioms of ZFC.

Comment: Right. So for all *infinite* cardinals $\kappa$ and all ordinals $\alpha$, we have that $|[\kappa,2^\kappa)|$ equals $\aleph_\alpha$ in some model. And at the same time, $|[\kappa,2^\kappa)| \leq 2^{2^\kappa}.$

Comment: Hmmm no wait that can't be right. I need to chew some more.

Comment: @user18921: Not quite all $\alpha$, because of the cofinality restriction, but otherwise the previous comment is right.

Comment: I'm still not getting it.... Which of the symbols are a function of the model chosen? For instance, is $|[\kappa,2^\kappa)|$ the "true" cardinality of this interval, or is it the cardinality internal to the model of interest?

Comment: @user18921: Everything that I’ve written is to be understood from the point of view of the model of interest. When I say, for instance, that $|[\omega,2^\omega)|$ can be $\omega_1$, I mean that if ZFC is consistent, it’s consistent with $|[\omega,2^\omega)|=\omega_1$ (or $\aleph_1$, if you insist). Of course that means that $\omega_1$ might also be the ‘true’ cardinality of the interval.